# command line batch file - define several customization

Tags: batch-file

I am using batch file (*.bat) to run several programs.

Each line, (such as myexe.exe) may take long time, so I want

1. Add a spinner when the line executed (first character '/', second: '-', third: '\', forth: sixth: '|', seventh: '/', and so on). How can I do that?
2. ensure that the line execute, and if not - It won't hung the process, but the following line will continue (in some cases).
3. ensure that the line execute, and if not - It won't hung the process, but the following line will not continue (in some cases, I want to break the process).
4. Can I define time out for the line execute?

How can I do the above?

Need code sample, please.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't your `myexe.exe` just output the spinner to the console? It can be enabled by passing the argument to the program, if you care about unused output. The same goes for the timeout.

Comment: I didn't understands. I ran myexe.exe - That may take hour (myexe.exe doesn't show any spinner. It is not the purpose of myexe.exe - It can for example run a database sql command, or may be a command line that delete millions of files. When running it I want to see some progress (such as spinner). I have seen that somewhere, but I don't know how doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've created:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "executable=notepad.exe"
set "work_dir=."

for /f "skip=5 tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('wmic process call create "%executable%"^,"%work_dir%"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;= " %%a in ("%%#") do (
       rem --In the part "%%a" equ "    ProcessID" the blank before the ProcessID is a single tab
       rem --Some (browser/online)editors could alert it to spaces!
       if not defined PID if "%%a" equ "    ProcessId" set "PID=%%b"
    )
)
if not defined PID echo Failed to start the process && exit /b 3

set s_time=%time%
set "_0=/"
set "_1=-"
set "_2=\"
set "_3=|"

set counter=0
set "line=."



:loop
echo executing %executable% [%s_time%]
set /a counter=counter+1
set /a mod=counter%%4
if %mod% equ 0 set line=%line%.

qprocess %PID% >nul 2>&1 && (

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
    echo %line%!_%mod%!
    pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 300 >nul
    cls
    endlocal
    goto :loop

) || (
    echo execution of %executable% finished [%time%]
)

endlocal
```

At the moment clearing the screen is mandatory , but may be will do the job for you? Also `WMIC` is not available for WinXP home edition.

Comment: I copy+paste the code as is.
I am testing that in windows 7 + windows 8.
I got an error: failed to start the process.

What does this code do?
Example : run myexe.exe (long executable code), and use that code?

Comment: @Eitan - it's described in the comments.Stackoverflow editor sets spaces where it finds tabs. in the condition `if "%%a" equ "    ProcessId"` set tab before `ProcessId`